# Any dhcp python library?

Tags: python, dhcp

Is there any library to help me instantiate a dhcp server in python?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are some in development and alpha verity :

- http://ostatic.com/pydhcpd/

Other servers:

- http://code.google.com/p/staticdhcpd/

And a library for working on dhcp too

- http://nixbit.com/cat/programming/libraries/pydhcplib/

DHCP command line query and testing tool

- http://code.google.com/p/dhquery/

Comment: dhquery and pydhcpd don't seem to be compatible with the version of pydhcplib available -- any clue which versions work? Otherwise they are all unusable.

Answer (score 4):

You might take a look at [pydhcplib](http://pydhcplib.tuxfamily.org/pmwiki/) or [anemon](http://anemon.org/pmwiki/index.php?n=General.Download) for starters.